# How to add a column to a pandas dataframe without column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame wich has 2 'columns'. The first column does not seem to have a column name, the second one is named `Speed`.

Here is a MRE:

```
from io import StringIO  # to read strings as files for read_csv

import pandas as pd

parts = [
    '[Level1]\nLocation = "London"\nType= "GTHY66"\n'
    'Date = "16-11-2021"\nEnergy level = "Critical zero"\n',
    '0.000   26.788\n0.027   26.807\n0.053   26.860'
]

lvl2_lines = "Speed\n" + parts[1]

df_level2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(lvl2_lines), sep='\t')
print(df_level2.columns)
print(df_level2)
```

**This was my output when I did the print statements:**

```
Index(['Speed'], dtype='object')
            Speed
0  0.000   26.788
1  0.027   26.807
2  0.053   26.860
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
Index(['Power', 'Speed'], dtype='object')
   Power   Speed
0  0.000  26.788
1  0.027  26.807
2  0.053  26.860
```

Comment: `df.columns = ['Power', 'Speed']` ?

Comment: It look slike you have a multiindex perhaps? Try df.reset_index()

Comment: @not_speshal no because I don't want to rename. I want to add because I only have one column

Comment: I already tried what @splash58 did but I received the following error:  `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements`

Comment: @HenryEcker Done that

Comment: `df[['Power', 'Speed']] = df['Speed'].str.split(r'\s+', 1, expand=True)`

Comment: [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas) with `df[['Power', 'Speed']] = df['Speed'].str.split(r'\s+', 1, expand=True).astype(float)` if needing numbers instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `split` the strings:

```
df[["Power", "Speed"]] = df["Speed"].str.split(expand=True).astype(float)

>>> df
    Speed  Power
0  26.788  0.000
1  26.807  0.027
2  26.860  0.053
```

Comment: We could just specify both column names `lvl2_lines = "Speed\n" + parts[1]` -> `lvl2_lines = "Power Speed\n" + parts[1]` then there's no need to split after the fact or change dtype. But this would push the question into typo territory. And `df_level2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(lvl2_lines), sep=r'\s+', engine='python')` to handle mixed spacing.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's a neat way to directly read correctly instead of manipulating later. I answered before OP posted that bit in his question tho :)